# How to implement elastic search not filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search version 1.7.5

I've taken some ideas from this post:
[Elastic search Not filter inside and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238710/elastic-search-not-filter-inside-and-filter)

the query below does not seem to be filtering out the items that are associated with `item_category_id` 17. Is there a syntax error that you can see? The terms defined outside the `not`, inside the `filters` array are working fine.

```
      {
      query: {
          filtered: {
              filter: {
                  and: {
                      filters: [
                          { not: {
                                  filter: {
                                      terms: {item_category_ids: [17] }
                                  }
                              }
                          },
                          { term: { user_inactive: false } },
                          { term: { kind: 1 } }
                      ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'm after.

```
{
      query: {
          filtered: {
              filter: {
                  and: [
                      { terms: { published_posted_community_ids: @community_ids } },
                      { term: { user_inactive: false } },
                      { terms: { kind: 1 } },
                      { not: { terms: { item_category_ids: 17 } } }
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

The [`filtered` and `and/not` queries have been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#_literal_or_literal_and_literal_and_literal_now_implemented_via_literal_bool_literal) in ES 2.0, you should use `bool/filter/must_not` instead like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "terms": {
                "item_category_ids": [
                  17
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user_inactive": false
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "kind": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For ES 1.7, you need to change the query to this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "terms": {
              "item_category_ids": [
                17
              ]
            }
          },
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user_inactive": false
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "kind": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified I am using elastic search version 1.7.5

Comment: No that's a query for ES 2 and later. I've updated my answer

Comment: I don't actually need to calculate a score for each post document, 'constant score' is unnecessary. The Query i posted below is what I'm after.

Comment: `constant_score` is a query that will always return score 1, exactly like `filtered`. It's a way of only providing a filter (no score) and no queries.

Comment: So, you are saying a default score is applied when using filtered? As in the example shown below?

Comment: yes, but since that solution works for you, just use it.

Comment: Thanks for the input.